# Why the input of a pure R script is different from a combination of R and Python script?

Tags: python, r, rpy2, statistics

I have this script in R :

```
from rpy import * 
r.library("robustbase") 
adjboxStats(c(11232.1, 234.2, 3445532344.3, 34302.3, 203.9, 232223.3, 3434.55), coef = 2.5, a = -4, b = 3, do.conf = TRUE, do.out = TRUE)
```

It gave me this output:

```
$stats
[1]    203.900   1834.375  11232.100 133262.800 232223.300

$n
[1] 7

$conf
[1] -67254.84  89719.04

$fence
[1]   -6963.467 5097118.725

$out
[1] 3445532344
```

---

The Same script but is a mix between R and python :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from rpy import * 
r.library("robustbase") 

r("adjboxStats")(r.c(11232.1, 234.2, 3445532344.3, 34302.3, 203.9, 232223.3, 3434.55), coef = 2.5, a = -4, b = 3, do_conf = True, do_out = True)
```

give me this output, it's missing the fence attribute (outliers).

```
{'out': [-344553234.30000001, 3445532344.3000002], 'stats': [203.90000000000001, 219.05000000000001, 7333.3250000000007, 133262.79999999999, 232223.29999999999], 'conf': [-66986.823877395305, 81653.473877395299], 'n': 8}
```

---

When I try to add the fence attribute like this:

```
print r("adjboxStats")(r.c(11232.1, 234.2, 3445532344.3, 34302.3, 203.9, 232223.3, 3434.55), coef = 2.5, a = -4, b = 3, do_conf = True, do_out = True, do_fence = True)
```

I get this error message:

```
rpy.RPy_RException: Error in function (x, coef = 1.5, a = -4, b = 3, do.conf = TRUE, do.out = TRUE)  :
  unused argument(s) (do.fence = TRUE)
```

does any one why this is happening?

Thanks!